# "Best practices" for typesetting historical or etymological notes in a mathematical text

Tags: best-practices, mathematics

When including historical or etymological notes in a mathematical text, what are the good options for typesetting them? As remarks? As footnotes? As paragraphs? As something else?

I suppose that an HTML analog could be the [`<aside>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) element.

Comment: Some books relegate historical remarks to the ends of chapters (just one example, Jech's *Set Theory*, 3rd ed.). As a sub(sub)section, often a single paragraph. I quite like this style. Minimally invasive and reliably easy to find.

Comment: I prefer footnotes to endnotes any day. Easy enough to skip, but doesn't force you to mark your spot while looking something up in another part of the book.

Answer (score 1):

I think for two options:

1. Marginal notes if your book has larges margins.
2. Text boxexs with titles over a color (gray) background.